# Plotting 3D random walk in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, random-walk

I want to plot 3-D random walk in Python. Something that is similar to picture given below. Can you suggest me a tool for that. I am trying to use matplotlib for it but getting confused on how to do it.
For now I have a `lattice` array of zeros which basically is `X*Y*Z` dimensional and holds the information where random walker has walked, turning `0`to `1` on each `(x,y,z)` that random walker has stepped.

How can I create 3D visual of walk? [image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following I think does what you are trying to do:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 10

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

xyz = []
cur = [0, 0, 0]

for _ in xrange(20):
    axis = random.randrange(0, 3)
    cur[axis] += random.choice([-1, 1])
    xyz.append(cur[:])

x, y, z = zip(*xyz)
ax.plot(x, y, z, label='Random walk')
ax.scatter(x[-1], y[-1], z[-1], c='b', marker='o')   # End point
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

This would give you a random walk looking something like this:

[image: random walk]

Comment: hey thanks this worked wonders :)